# Okhttp3 Network Interceptor Chain Optimizations

Tags: android, kotlin, networking, caching, okhttp

I need a little help understanding things a little clearer. I have a network interceptor chain where I'm passing the cache as one of the headers to be added to the chain. I've looked into cache control and was wondering if there are any options to make optimizations app side that could be made to avoid a websocket timing out. Don't know where along the chain its taking the longest to receive a response back and I would like to pin point it.

For visibility the chain currently looks like this

```
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response = chain.run {
        proceed(
            request()
                .newBuilder()
                .addHeader(app, version)
                .addHeader(device, someDevice)
                .addHeader(cache, CACHE_MAX_AGE})
                .build()
        )
    }
```

Could someone pls explain if there would be any advantage in using cache control `.cacheControl()` over passing the cache as a header parameter using `.addheader()`.

Did a little research about chains.

Here's what I was thinking of trying,

1. Giving enough time for the longest operation/header takes to complete in the current chain by separating the chain and seeing what's the average time they all take to complete
2. Taking a piece by piece approach and passing them one at a time and then building the entire object with the allowing enough time at each step to its respective time to be able to complete in the case is not consistent for each individual and fluctuates in given network environments/situations so adjustments could be made
3. or if I know how long this chain currently takes to complete as is in a bunch of different use cases I can estimate a total time to all my chain to complete on the network and just give it that time to complete.

Pls let me know thoughts or if I'm way off and none of this can be done is feasible/optimal or if anyone has any other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The time to return a response through the interceptors chain is truly negligible.

Your attention is best focused on improving cache hit rates and reducing the total amount of data transmitted.